# Modeling with Python

Tags: python, modeling, scripting

I am new with Python programming, especially in Blender. I would like to know the possibilities of modeling with some scripts. I am currently modeling an object around a scan. I have to scan an object (with the Isense scanner), then modelize something aroung this object with blender.

I have more than 100 models to make and the base is always the same:

1. Create a point field that will stick the scanne (nearly always a kind of tube but the size differs sometimes)
2. Create a alveolar structure on this model (Voronoi diagram)

Do you know how I could do this ?

Comment: I just edited your answer, but I was not sure what you meant by "on base of a scanne." I also don't know what you mean by "scanne"...perhaps "scan"? Please edit your answer to explain.

Comment: Scanne = scanner?

Comment: Yes sorry, scanne = scan (I use the scanner Isense to scan some objects)

Answer (score 3):

For your first step you don't need to use python, create a base and save it, then you can use that file as a starting point for each new object you create.

The simplest way to create a mesh object using python would be to define a list of vertices and faces that make up the mesh.

```
import bpy

verts = [(-1,  1,   0),
         ( 1,  1,   0),
         ( 2, -3,   0),
         (-2, -1,   0),
         (-1,  1.5, 1),
         ( 1,  1.5, 1),
        ]

# faces are a list of indices to each vertex from the above list
faces = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 5, 4]]

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name="New Mesh")
mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('New object', mesh)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
```

You might want to get familiar with the [bmesh module](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html) which is used to perform most of the modelling tasks we do on mesh objects. The linked page contains an example of creating and editing a mesh.

As you don't know python very well yet I would suggest first trying out the [sverchok](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok) addon. It uses nodes to generate mesh objects. The links on sverchoks home page are getting old so you may want to start with [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKcn9kW3JXE&index=55&list=PLsbztkb4az9iEow8vgB0guWe1kd1Gw6Dy) to get an idea of what you can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!!
Im gonna try what you said :-)
True, I m realky new with Python so I have to improve my basic skills first

Just, for the first answer, I use the same base for every models but I though that it was possible to attache and fix this base on the new scan. Hard to explain with words:
- I open the scan in Blender
- I open the base/model
- I attache them together
- and then I create the Voronoi structure on it

Comment: It sounds like creating a mesh object with python might not be what you want. You can use *File->Append* to copy an object from another blend file into the new scan file and use a boolean modifier to join them into one solid mesh, this could be automated with a python script.